# How to open a .SO file and use it in AWS Lambda Function

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, ldap, aws-lambda-layers

I am using the Python module 'Bonsai' for one of my projects in AWS. Based on the documentation of the library, the Bonsai module does not work in a Linux environment via pip installation. Therefore, I installed the Bonsai module in WSL and added it to my Lambda Layer. When I try to run my Lambda Function
I get this error:

`Unable to import lambda_function: libldap-2.5.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`.

"lambda_function" is the handler for my AWS Lambda function.
These are the files that are in the bonsai module:[(in WSL)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XQUxl.png)
Heres the layout of my Lambda Function: [In AWS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DPxWq.png)
. I call the Bonsai module by using `import bonsai`

I have tried adding the bonsai module as a folder in the Lambda Function Layout but I get the same error.

Thank Yall Very much!

Comment: Use container lambda to properly package all dependencies.